# IMAP on Heroku - Unknown command: AUTHENTICATE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, imap

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, usessl = true, certs = nil, verify = false)
imap.authenticate('XOAUTH2', user.gmail, user.google_token)
```

The above code is giving me an error when I run it on a Heroku Scheduler function:

```
Unknown command: AUTHENTICATE
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/imap.rb:1158:in `get_tagged_response'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/imap.rb:1210:in `block in send_command'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/imap.rb:1192:in `send_command'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/imap.rb:418:in `authenticate'
/app/app/models/user.rb:161:in `block in screen_email_for_probable_products'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in `each'
/app/app/models/user.rb:155:in `screen_email_for_probable_products'
/app/lib/tasks/scheduler.rake:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
```

I have previously tested this function local development without issues. Anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem is because this needs to be re-initalized everytime I want to authenticate with a different user.

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, usessl = true, certs = nil, verify = false)
```